# Uniform Convergence of $e^{-nx}$ on $[0,1]$, $[a,1]$, $(0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

Let {$f_n$} be a sequence of functions defined on $\mathbb R$ by $f_n(x) : = e^{-nx}$.

Does it converge uniformly on $[0,1]$? Does it converge uniformly on  $[a,1]$ with $0 < a \leq 1$ ? Does it converge uniformly on $(0,1]$ ?

Clearly, {$f_n$} converges  pointwise to $f(x)$ defined by

\begin{cases} 
      1 &  x= 0 \\
      0 &  x\in  (0,1] 
   \end{cases}

How do I prove that it doesn't converge uniformly on any of the intervals?

Comment: I think the restriction on a should be $0<a\leq1$

Answer (score 3):

The pointwise limit is not continuous on $[0, 1]$, so $f_n$ couldn't converge to $f$ uniformly on $[0, 1]$.

This should provide an answer to the first and a hint to the other two.